# Add another validation to make data pairing work

Tags: javascript

I am creating a matchmaking function where 2 players with the same weight will be paired.

It is currently working now based on the same weight. Now, I added another condition where players have their own level. My first condition is based on the same weight. This is working. My 2nd condition is about "CLASS", if the players have the same class, they should not be matched/paired.

```
const source = [
    {
        entryID: 1,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 2,
        entryName: "player2",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 3,
        entryName: "player3",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 4,
        entryName: "player4",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],
    },

];

console.log(combine(source))

function combine(data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2) {
    const groups = [], related = [], sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight),
        alreadyInRela = (setX, eName) => {
            let list = [...setX, eName]
            return related.some(rela => list.every(l => rela.has(l)))
        };
    
    sortedData.forEach((el, indx) => {
        let place = groups.findIndex( // find a place in a group forEach element, use indx as track
            g => g.names.size < maxGroupSize              // is the group incomplete ?
                && !g.names.has(el.entryName)             // is entryName not in the group list (names Set) ?
                && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different
                && !alreadyInRela(g.names, el.entryName) // is (entryName + group list) does not already used ?
        )

        if (place < 0) { // not found -> create new group
            let names = new Set().add(el.entryName)                      // create new group
            groups.push({ names, indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight })  // group constitutive info 
            related.push(names)                                      // keep track of group list
        } else { // find a place in a group
            groups[place].names.add(el.entryName)  // related list is also updated
            groups[place].indxs.push(indx)        // add indx to retreive element in sortedData 
        }
    });

    return groups.reduce((r, g, i) => { // build result
        if (g.indxs.length > 1) {
            let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x => sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
            r[key] = []
            g.indxs.forEach(x => r[key].push(sortedData[x]))
        }
        return r
    }, {})
}
```

My current output:

```
{
    0_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 1,
            entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 2,
            entryName: "player2",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ],
    1_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 3,
            entryName: "player3",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 4,
            entryName: "player4",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ]
}
```

Target output (As we can see here, the players with the same CLASS are not joined/combined. This is what I need to aim for):

```
{
    0_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 1,
            entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 3,
            entryName: "player3",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ],
    1_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 2,
            entryName: "player2",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 4,
            entryName: "player4",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that classes may have duplicate values?

Comment: No, it is not possible to have a duplicated value/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code stores all the classes in the group and compares new players' classes before insertion:

```js
const source = [
    {
        entryID: 1,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 2,
        entryName: "player2",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 3,
        entryName: "player3",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 4,
        entryName: "player4",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],
    },

];

console.log(combine(source))

function combine(data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2) {
    const groups = [], related = [], sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight),
        alreadyInRela = (setX, eName) => {
            let list = [...setX, eName]
            return related.some(rela => list.every(l => rela.has(l)))
        };
    
    sortedData.forEach((el, indx) => {
        let place = groups.findIndex( // find a place in a group forEach element, use indx as track
            g => g.names.size < maxGroupSize              // is the group incomplete ?
                && !g.names.has(el.entryName)             // is entryName not in the group list (names Set) ?
                && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different
                && !alreadyInRela(g.names, el.entryName) // is (entryName + group list) does not already used ?
                && el.class.every(c => !g.usedClasses.has(c)) // check class
        )

        if (place < 0) { // not found -> create new group
            let names = new Set().add(el.entryName)                      // create new group
            groups.push({ names, indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight, usedClasses: new Set(el.class) })  // group constitutive info 
            related.push(names)                                      // keep track of group list
        } else { // find a place in a group
            groups[place].names.add(el.entryName)  // related list is also updated
            el.class.forEach(c => groups[place].usedClasses.add(c)) // add classes
            groups[place].indxs.push(indx)        // add indx to retreive element in sortedData 
        }
    });

    return groups.reduce((r, g, i) => { // build result
        if (g.indxs.length > 1) {
            let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x => sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
            r[key] = []
            g.indxs.forEach(x => r[key].push(sortedData[x]))
        }
        return r
    }, {})
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a question.

I tried to apply your suggestion. But when 2 data class are [''], they are not getting matched/paired. I think this code is considering also the empty string as a class? Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rain0221/0Lazgbo5/13/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/laU7kpU4UduF here's the screenshot of the result for better visualization

Answer (score 1):

I would absolutely be looking at using [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for this kind of thing, rather than monolithic sorting functions. But to stick with plain old functions, it will be easier to handle if you start extracting logic into different functions, especially if you decide to change any of the group logic later.
Specific functions with descriptive names will save much headache. Example:

```
// source data omitted for brevity

const maxGroupSize = 2;

// Check if a player's classes clash with the group's
const groupHasClassConflict = (group, playerClasses) => {
    const groupClasses = group.reduce((output, groupPlayer) => {
        groupPlayer.class.forEach(groupPlayerClass => {
            if (!output.includes(groupPlayerClass)) output.push(groupPlayerClass);
        });
        return output;
    }, []);
    for (let i = 0; i < playerClasses.length; i++) {
        if (groupClasses.includes(playerClasses[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Check if a group is suitable for a player
const groupIsSuitable = (group, playerWeight, playerClasses) => {
    if (group.length < maxGroupSize && group[0].weight === playerWeight) {
        if (!groupHasClassConflict(group, playerClasses)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Match players into groups
const sortGroups = (playerArray) => {
    let groupIndex = 0;
    return playerArray.reduce((output, player) => {
        // Check each group to see if there's a spot for this player
        for (const group in output) {
            if (groupIsSuitable(output[group], player.weight, player.class)) {
                output[group].push(player);
                return output;
            }
        }
        // If not, start a new group
        output[`${groupIndex}_${player.weight}`] = [ player ];
        groupIndex++;
        return output;
    }, {});
}

// sortGroups(source);
```

Classes would allow you to encapsulate that logic into Players and Groups, and make the code more efficient if groups start getting bigger.
I'd also tend to avoid using the keyword `class` as a key name - though it won't throw an error while it's nested in an object, running it through a function that uses destructuring will cause issues.